# Is there another way to explain that, in pure rolling, no tangential acceleration is acting on the contacting point relative to the surface?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

For pure rolling condition of a rigid circle on a surface, most textbooks will use this definition:
$$v_{cm} = R\omega. \tag{1}$$
Then, they will differentiate the equation and get
$$a_{cm} = R\alpha. \tag{2}$$ From this result, we can conclude that the contacting point will not experience any tangential acceleration.

However, I personally prefer the definition that pure rotation is when the contacting points will be at rest. Using this definition, we can also derive $v_{cm} = R\omega.$ Then, with the similar differentiation process, we can arrive at the same conclusion.

Nevertheless, I still find it hard to understand why the contacting point must have no tangential acceleration relative to the surface if we require the contacting point to be instantaneously at rest. Is there another way to derive this conclusion?

Comment: If a point is _always_ at rest w.r.t ground, it has no acceleration?

Comment: @IndischerPhysiker But the point is only instantaneously at rest when it is contacting with the surface, right? I don't know if we can treat the contacting points at different moments as the same point in the rolling motion.